# How to get next element's value - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` like this :

```
<div id="div_more_info">
    <input placeholder="title" name="title_info" class="title_info" style="margin: 1px" type="text">
    <input placeholder="des" name="des_info" class="des_info" style="margin: 1px;margin-left: 24px" type="text">

    <input placeholder="title" name="title_info" class="title_info" style="margin: 1px" type="text">
    <input placeholder="des" name="des_info" class="des_info" style="margin: 1px;margin-left: 24px" type="text">
</div>
```

now I would like to get `title - value` of each row of my div:

```
$("#div_more_info .title_info").each(function () {
    var title_info = $(this).val();
    var des_info = $(this).next().find('.des_info').val();

    alert(title_info);
    alert(des_info);
});
```

my code shows `title_info` value but `des_info` shows as a undefined .

Comment: `$(this).next('.des_info').val();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need of `.find()`, only with `.next()` you will reach `.des_info` node.

Instead of

```
var des_info = $(this).next().find('.des_info').val();
```

Use

```
var des_info = $(this).next('.des_info').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either [Kartikeya Khosla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3852595/kartikeya-khosla) solution or could use:

```
var des_info = $(this).next().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `next()` function of jquery.

**Updated Script:**

```
$("#div_more_info .title_info").each(function () {
  var title_info = $(this).val();
  var des_info = $(this).next().val();

  alert(title_info);
  alert(des_info);
});
```

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/x5b5pdb3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this short:

```
  $(".title_info,.des_info").each(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
  });
```